# eclipse-pythone : Is it possible to enable a breakpoint only after n hit counts?

Tags: python, eclipse, centos6

I know that in eclipse you can set a breakpoint to break after n times. I can't do it in eclipse while debugging python. Am I missing something ? using eclipse Kepler and centOs 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

given the following code:

```
for i in range(10):
    print i
```

after you set a breakpoint in Eclipse, in this case on the `print i` line, write click the breakpoint itself and choose 'Breakpoint Properties...' then in the 'enable condition' text box, you can write a block of code that has access to global as well as local program arguments and will do something like:

```
val = eval(condition, frame.f_globals, frame.f_locals)
```

you are responsible for writing the condition code, something like:

[image]